# WIF: SessionAuthenticationModule Always Null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wif

I'm trying to get WIF set up on an MVC project I'm working on but to no avail.  The issue I'm having is that `FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule` is always null.  I have added the following lines to web.config under `configSections`:

```
<section name="system.identityModel"
    type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
<section name="system.identityModel.services"
    type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
```

I also attempted to init the module:

```
<modules>
  <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule"
       type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
       preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
```

Still nothing.  I installed WIF through nuget.  I noticed that the namespace for WIF for most of the docs online (like what I posted above) is `System.IdentityModel` whereas the namespace for the what I have through nuget is `Microsoft.IdentityModel`.  Could this be causing the trouble?

A few specs:

Standard MVC 4 Project

Using `Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll` v3.5.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.identitymodel.xxx is the .Net 4.5 version if WIF where everything is merged into the core framework.

Microsoft.identitymodel.xxx is the .net 4 version that is installed separately.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install WIF 4 with nuget. .Net framework 4.5 has built-in support for this library.
your web.config must be like this:

```
    <configSections>
<section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
</configSections>
```

and:

```
<system.webServer>
<modules>
  <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
  <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
</modules>
</system.webServer>
```